# Clear cache in ionic application?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have read so many blogs it says there is a bug in

```
$scope.logout = function() {

    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    $state.go('home');

};
```

is there any solution for clearing cache using ionic code or using some angular code??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using this plugin you can clear cache

Follow this steps

1) install this plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cache

2)write this line where you want to clear your cache

```
window.cache.clear()
```

Comment: thanks, I used this one. "cordova.plugin.cache.clear()"